# GraphDB Lucene index - how to exclude property URIs from search results?

Tags: lucene, graphdb

It seems that by default a Lucene index that indexes "uris" will index both nodes and properties. How can properties be excluded from search results?

The documentation shows a setting:

```
luc:exclude luc:setParam "bnode".
```

However its only valid values are "literal", "bnode", and "uri". How can property URIs be excluded? (they are not something that a search would be interested in).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/full-text-search.html and not https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/lucene-graphdb-connector.html ?

The doc doesn't show what you show above, but shows

```
luc:exclude luc:setParam "hello.*"
```

which means "exclude strings that match the regex".

Which things to index is controlled by

```
luc:include luc:setParam "literal" # literal, uri, centre
```

If I understand correctly, you want to index URIs of nodes, but not URIs of outgoing properties? Then the answer would depend on the kind of molecule you are traversing.

- `luc:include luc:setParam "literal centre"` will index only the central node URIs, which is probably what you want
- with `luc:excludePredicates` you can list all properties you want to exclude, but that will also cut out the nodes that they reach...